# Strange reputation behaviour

Tags: support, voting, reputation

Relating to [this question on Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356136/strange-reputation-behaviour), I'd just like to confirm that there's no odd voting behaviour going on with [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53503/modifying-hobby-ranks), as it's an old question and I've just had two upvotes for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case I've just checked in on our tools for spotting strange voting behaviour and there's nothing weird going on.

I agree with Miniman, your question just got new attention from being bumped by an edit.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for checking, @doppelgreener.  (Just making sure).

Answer (score 7):

Almost certainly nothing odd happening there. [It got edited](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/53503/revisions), which bumped it back to the front page. When this happens to a question, it generally gets some eyes on it which haven't seen it before, and this often leads to some more votes.

Comment: I must admit, I didn't think to check the editing.

Comment: @Paul I only know cos I saw it on the front page :)